# Difference between file .crypt and .crypt5

Tags: file, encryption

What is the difference between the files with an extension .crypt versus file with and extension .crypt5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.crypt5 is the newest version of What's App database files, actually they are using .crypt7 now (29/04/2014)

There are ways to convert .crypt5 to crypt but I'm still researching. I'll get back to the thread once I'm done.